# MySQL: Finding multiple duplicate records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

From the table *albums* below, I need to pull out the album_ids where at least 3 musician_ids are matching, e.g. the expected result is *100* and *102*, as they both contain the musician_ids 2, 3 and 4.

```
id    album_id    musician_id
1     100         1
2     100         2
3     100         3
4     100         4
5     101         3
6     101         4
7     101         5
8     101         6
9     102         2
10    102         3
11    102         4
12    102         7
13    103         1
14    103         2
15    103         8
16    103         9
```

Using MySQL Workbench. All assistance gratefully appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  `album_id`, COUNT(`album_id`) AS `count` 
FROM 
   albums 
GROUP BY 
   `album_id` 
HAVING 
   `count` >= 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just shows each album_id with the total count of musician_ids attached to it, so long as that total is >= 3. I'm looking for where those records match, i.e. album_ids with >= matching musician_ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is a set-within-sets problem.  Here is a typical solution:

```
select album_id
from albums
where musician_id in (2, 3, 4)
group by album_id
having count(distinct musician_id) = 3;
```

EDIT:

Your revised question seems rather different from the original, but I can see where the ambiguity lies.

The answer is:

```
select a1.album_id, a2.album_id, count(*) as nummatches,
       group_concat(a1.musician_id) as musicians
from albums a1 join
     albums a2
     on a1.musician_id = a2.musician_id and a1.album_id < a2.album_id
group by a1.album_id, a2.album_id
having count(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works well if I'm _only_ looking for album_ids containing 2, 3 and 4, but I'm looking for album_ids where _any_ 3 musician_ids match, e.g. album_ids which both contain 126, 472 and 859.
And perhaps I should have been clearer in the original, but the results also need to display the matching musician_ids as well, e.g. 

    100      2, 3, 4
    102      2, 3, 4